# trying to reverse the string with "_" fixed at point

Tags: python, string

```
def r(s): 
  str = []
  for i in len(s):
   if (s[i]=='_'): 
    str = s[i] + str
    continue   
   str = s[i] + str
  return str
```

I tried using the above code to convert the following string

**Input:** `ab_cde`

**Expected Output:** `ed_cba`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to check all the positions of the underscore `_`, save them and reverse the string without them, to insert them again after reversing.

```
import re

def r(s):
  # check where all the underscore are
  underscore_positions = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('_', s)]
  # get list of reversed chars without underscores
  reversed_chars = [c for c in reversed(s) if c != '_']
  # put underscore back where they where
  for p in underscore_positions:
    reversed_chars.insert(p, '_')
  # profit
  return "".join(reversed_chars)
```

The function can be modified to have a different fixed character.

I also uses the package `re` for the regex function to identify the `_`, you can do with a simple loop as `underscore_positions = [i for i, c in enumerate(s) if c =='_']` if you prefer.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = 'ab_cde'

out = ''
for a, b in zip(s, s[::-1]):
    if b != '_' and a != '_':
        out += b
    else:
        out += a

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
ed_cba
```

---

EDIT: For more fixed points:

```
s = 'ab_cde_f_ghijk_l'

i, out = iter(ch for ch in s[::-1] if ch != '_'), ''

out = ''.join(ch if ch == '_' else next(i) for ch in s)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
lk_jih_g_fedcb_a
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with a string with more than one fixed point, e.g. `"ab_cde_f_ghijk_l"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fixed_reverse(s, ch):
    idxs = [-1] + [i for i, x in enumerate(s) if x == ch] + [len(s)]
    idxs = [x - i + 1 for i, x in enumerate(idxs)]
    chars = "".join(x for x in s if x != ch)[::-1]
    return ch.join(chars[a:b] for a, b in zip(idxs[:-1], idxs[1:]))

>>> fixed_reverse("ab_cde_f_ghijk_l", "_")
'lk_jih_g_fedcb_a'
```

This works by:

1. Storing the locations of the fixed-point character `"_"`.
2. Reversing the string with the `"_"` characters removed.
3. Inserting the `"_"` back into the correct locations.